# Commerce LineItem Option validation

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, modules

I have Line Item options that I'm trying to validate in a module. I'm using the example code from [the docs here](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/orders-carts.html#line-item-options-and-notes) on the front-end of the cart.

Below that it says:

> Commerce does not validate the options and note parameters. If you’d like to limit user input, use front-end validation or use the Model::EVENT_DEFINE_RULES event to add validation rules for the LineItem model.

Using that and the [Event Generator](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/extend/events.html) I've come up with this:

```
Event::on(LineItem::class, Model::EVENT_DEFINE_RULES, function (DefineRulesEvent $event) {
  $event->rules[] = [['options'], 'required'];
});
```

But no validation is performed; I can continue in the cart without any options input. My options show based on the quantity of the line item; for example, if the line item quantity is 3, 3 input fields show.

Can anyone please help me get this to work?

Comment: Where is your code located, is it inside the init method of you module?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Luke. I use the new Generator plugin to generate the module so it's inside the `attachEventHandlers` which is called inside the `init` method. It actually peforms the validation on a cart in the control panel, just not on the front-end.

Comment: Ok so it seems to be because options are submitted as an empty string inside the array? So it's seeing option[name] = "" and thinking that meets the `required` rule. Changing it to `$event->rules[] = [['options'], 'string', 'min' => 2];` indeed trips it up. Now I need to work out how I can make that work for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like adding validation to `options` is difficult (in this case, I want to enforce an email but not another field.) So I'm going to use front-end validation instead.

Edit: this doesn't exactly answer my question, but I was able to make it work:

`$event->rules[] = [['options'], 'each', 'rule' => ['each', 'rule' => ['required']]];`